# python numpy arrays. How to slice multiple arrays in an efficient way?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i got a problem to solve and i cannot come up with a good solution.

To ease it down I got an array of 10x10 and i want to slice out "little arrays" of 3x3. Right now i do this the following way:

```
array = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))

patch = np.array(array[:3, :3]

for n in range(3, 10, 3):
   for m in range(3, 10, 3):
      patch = numpy.append(patch, array[n:n+3, m:m+3]
```

i basically create the numpy array patch with the first slice and append all other slices afterwards. The problem with this is that its horribly slow and does not do good use of the slicing opportunities of numpy. I need to do this for a high number of much bigger arrays.
Can anyone give me any advice on how to make this more efficient?
1000 thanks!

Comment: why append `patch`? If patch is a slice ie `patch = array[n:n+3,m:m+3]`, any values changed on `patch` will be changed on `array`. If it is a memory issue, I would suggest looking into [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: hi and thank you for your response.What i want to have in the end is an array (patch) which contains every 3x3 slice possible on the big array array. i do this the ugly way in creating the array with one entry (slice 1) to get the right dimensions (i am using more dimensional arrays in my work) and append all other slices afterwards. you say in the way i do it i change array too? i dont want to do that, array should be independent from patch

Comment: I still dont quite see why you want to split the array into patches, or why it is a problem that changing patch changes that part of the array. Also, by using append without setting axis you turn your 2d array into 1d I believe. Could you try to show what you want to do through some simple example?

Comment: So these are 2d windows on a large array?  It doesn't look like they overlap?  For a 1d array, simple reshaping will work; with 2d we have to be more careful.

Comment: Iterative `append` on arrays is bad.  It's better to build a list iteratively, and turn that into an array at the end.  Or pre allocate the result, and assign slices iteratively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is entirely down to using `numpy.append`. `append` creates a new array each time you use it. As your patch array gets bigger this will take progressively longer.

Instead, use a presized array (you already know the final size of the patch array), and avoid making intermediary copies of any data.

```
# setup
x, y = 999, 999
array = np.arange(x * y)
array.shape = x, y
little_array_size = 3

# creates an array of "little arrays"
patch = np.empty(array.size, dtype=int)
patch.shape = -1, little_array_size, little_array_size

i = 0
for n in range(0, array.shape[0], little_array_size):
    for m in range(0, array.shape[1], little_array_size):
        # uses view, so data is copied straight from array to patch
        patch[i,:] = array[n:n+little_array_size, m:m+little_array_size]
        i += 1

patch.shape = -1 # flattens array
```

The above takes about a third of second on my computer (two orders of magnitude faster than using `numpy.append` (20+ seconds)).

Comment: ah that was it what i was looking for. thanks alot, got it to work a hundred times faster.